# Tool recommendation to prick bamboo nodes

Tags: hand-tools, tool-selection, tool-identification

I am looking for some kind of tool which I can use to prick through a bamboo.

To be more specific, bamboo is hollow inside. There is just some kind of plates "the nodes" which is connecting the inside. I want to prick these nodes, so the bamboo is hollow in full.

The bamboo I work with is 1 meter long. So the tool would need to be at least 50cm long.

Can you name any tools which could be used for that? Maybe there is even one existing which I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The people over at Bamboocraft.net seem to say that the best way is to get a piece of metal rod (rebar will do) and simply bash through. If it's hard to do, you can also heat the rod up in a fire and it will supposedly burn through very easily.

You'll want a rod/bar which is a touch thinner than the inside diameter of the bamboo cane so that you don't split your cane while doing this.

Relevant link here: http://www.bamboocraft.net/forums/showthread.php?t=2639

Comment: Thank you for that link WhatEvil. I was not aware of that website which I will certainly attend more often now. I am going with the rebar and try to smooth the inside with some sandpaper as needed. Here is some hope I don't need any heat :)